# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification found versions 25.2.0, 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After my android studio today from version 2.2.3 to 2.3 then i got this error in build.gradle on the 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0' dependencies.
But the project still can be run.
and i run a Gradle dependency report to see what my full tree of dependencies. Display as below. But i still do not know how to fix this error.

**Dependency Tree**

```html
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- project :mylibrary
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- project :tastytoast
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
+--- com.android.support:design:25.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.2.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.2.3
|    \--- com.android.support:design:23.2.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0 -> 3.3.1
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.github.lovetuzitong:MultiImageSelector:1.2
|    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0 -> 2.5.2
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.0.3
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3 -> 25.2.0
|         +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 -> 25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1 (*)
+--- com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1
+--- com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1
+--- com.foursquare:placepicker:0.5.7
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5 -> 2.6.1
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 25.2.0
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.12 -> 1.0.13
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.12.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.12.0
|    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.12.0
|    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.12.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.12.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.12.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|         \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:0.12.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.2
\--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8
     \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha8

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

**my gradle:**

```js
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
    compile project(":tastytoast")
    compile files('libs/BaiduLBS_Android.jar')
    compile files('libs/IndoorscapeAlbumPlugin.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.lovetuzitong:MultiImageSelector:1.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.foursquare:placepicker:0.5.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.12.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one Support Library dependency that does not have a `-> 25.2.0` after it is `com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0`, which was included from `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0`

So add that line with the `25.2.0` dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your command. when i add compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0' and 'compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0' but all layout got error like that        java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Toolbar_buttonGravity
 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:244)
 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:231)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: Are you seeing those errors when you put your app on a device or just in the layout preview? If it is just in the layout preview, you'll want to make sure you've updated to the latest stable Android Studio, clean and rebuilt, etc.

Comment: yes it only shows in the layout preview. and i already have the latest version of the android studio installed but it is useless my all layout still show error message as below after i upgrade android studio to 2.3. Render errors: 1. Failed to instantiate or more classes 2. Can't make a decor toolbar out of MockView 3. Render problem 4. Miss styles

Comment: So the original `build.gradle` error is solved and your app installs correctly? It sounds like this question is indeed answered and you should ask separate questions for your new issues.

Comment: Yes  after add : compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0' and 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' build.gradle error is solved. Thank you very much for your reply and advice.