# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, gradle

I have been spending some time on this but yet I still can't find this `animated-vector-drawable` dependency that is using sdkVersion `24`. I have manually tried to change the version code for all `com.android.support` libraries to use version `25` as opposed to `23` but still I am getting the error. Where am I mixing the version codes? Are there any possible duplicates to my libraries?

I have cleaned, rebuilt and synced Gradles files with the project amongst other troubleshooting tips including trying to seek some insight from the following SOP posts but still the error is persistent.

Resources visited:

1. [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)
2. [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581963/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version)
3. [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification found versions 25.2.0, 25.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074234/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

> Error:(33, 13) All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.1.0. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0` and `com.android.support:design:23.1.0`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "trip.it.co.za.tripit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "AIzaSyAiM1JxYFPr4D4igrPjFJJRXJloheKjyLs"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "AIzaSyAiM1JxYFPr4D4igrPjFJJRXJloheKjyLs"
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    //wasabeef
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.github.zzz40500:AndroidSweetSheet:221317862b'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.androidquery:androidquery:0.26.9'
}
```

**Update:**

So I wanted to know where this `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0` library is referenced in the project but strangely, no occurrence of it is found anywhere.

Comment: Maybe some of your third party libraries using different versions of support libraries.

Comment: why u have two different version of "com.android.support:design" (23.0.0 & 23.1.0) alongside each other!?

Comment: I have commented the old one `23.0.0` and the error still persists..

Comment: I think @Alex is right, your third party libraries are using different version support libraries. So you might have to update those libraries.

Comment: @SagarPujari Update them how?

Comment: @Harold_Finch Check online or through android studio for each and every library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took some time in understanding the error message so I changed all `com.android.support` libraries to that of the latest - `v25.3.1` and added the two libraries below:

1. `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1`
2. `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1`

Then I changed my `compileSdkVersion` from `23` to `25`.

I then changed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`

And all was happy.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you dude.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Happy coding :-)

Comment: Found versions 26.0.1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0

Please help me